# Error in [.data.frame`(attr, , region) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

Estou querendo usar o `fortify` para plotar um gráfico no R:

```
PaísX <- fortify(BRmap, region = "ID_2") %>%  
  mutate(id = as.integer(id)) %>%
  full_join(BRmap@data, by =c("id" = "ID_2")) %>%
  select(c(id, long, lat, order, hole, piece, group, NAME_2))
```

Mas quando rodo a linha, apresenta esse erro:

> Error in [.data.frame`(attr, , region) : undefined columns selected<

O BRMap é um shapefile que pode ser encontrado no https://gadm.org

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo porque a coluna `ID_2` não existe no objeto `BRmap`, como a mensagem de erro está informando.

Ao ler o arquivo baixado da página indicada, podemos verificar que nenhuma de suas colunas é tem nome `ID_2`, mas há a coluna `GID_2` (não sei se é a que deseja de fato usar).

```
BRmap <- readRDS("gadm36_BRA_2_sp.rds")
names(BRmap)
 [1] "GID_0"     "NAME_0"    "GID_1"     "NAME_1"    "NL_NAME_1" "GID_2"    
 [7] "NAME_2"    "VARNAME_2" "NL_NAME_2" "TYPE_2"    "ENGTYPE_2" "CC_2"     
[13] "HASC_2"
```

Algo que ajuda muito há debugar os códigos construídos com o pipe operator (`%>%`) é rodar o código que vai até um pipe, e depois até o seguinte e assim por diante. Isso ajuda a identificar onde está o erro. Neste caso o erro já está na primeira linha.

Ademais, recomendo remover a linha com o `mutate(...)`, pois os IDs não são numéricos e, ao convertê-los para inteiros terá apenas `NA` em toda a coluna.

```
head(BRmap$GID_2)
[1] "BRA.1.1_1" "BRA.1.2_1" "BRA.1.3_1" "BRA.1.4_1" "BRA.1.5_1" "BRA.1.6_1"
```

Por fim, temos:

```
library(dplyr)
PaísX <- ggplot2::fortify(BRmap, region = "GID_2") %>% 
  full_join(BRmap@data, by =c("id" = "GID_2")) %>%
  select(c(id, long, lat, order, hole, piece, group, NAME_2))
```